# Javascript: setInterval for multiple chart updates

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, setinterval

I'm trying to display three Google Chart Gauges on a page to represent data from three temperature sensors.  I have a JS function `GetCurrentTemperature` that returns the three temperature values in an array.  I want the gauges to update at regular intervals.  I've had this working fine with a single gauge, but when I try and use `setInterval` for the three charts, they're not updating.  The code I'm using is listed below.

```
function drawTemperatureGauges() {

var currentTemp = GetCurrentTemperature();
var gaugeCount = currentTemp.length;

var options = {
    width: 200, 
    height: 200,
    redFrom: 65,         
    redTo: 80,
    yellowFrom: 50, 
    yellowTo: 65,
    minorTicks: 5,
    max: 80
};

for(var i=0; i<gaugeCount; i++) {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Temp', currentTemp[i] ]
    ]);

    var divName = 'gauge'.concat(i+1).concat('_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById(divName));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    setInterval(function() {
        var cTemp = GetCurrentTemperature();
        data.setValue(0, 1, cTemp[i]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

I assume it's because I'm using `i` inside the anonymous `setInterval` function. I've looked at posts related to closures and also ones that specify the use of `let` rather than `var` but I still can't work out what syntax I need.

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Bbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try locking in a closure like this?

```
for(var i=0; i<gaugeCount; i++) {
  drawGauge(i);
}

function drawGauge(i) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Temp', currentTemp[i] ]
    ]);

    var divName = 'gauge'.concat(i+1).concat('_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById(divName));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    setInterval(function() {
        var cTemp = GetCurrentTemperature();
        data.setValue(0, 1, cTemp[i]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thinking "outside the function".  Thank you!